# Creating RAW Packets with Go 1.5 on MacOSX

Tags: macos, sockets, go, packet

I am trying to do some basic packet crafting for a testing tool I am working on, but I can not seem to get the packet crafting to work (I am using Go 1.5 on OSX  and am running as root.)

I am using the following code ([taken from here](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/raw-sockets-in-go-link-layer/)) to try and create an ICMP packet, but when I try to specify say specific options in the IP header it does not seem to work.  Further when I look at this packet in wireshark it shows up as protocol 255 (unknown).

I have read that on Linux system you can use AF_PACKET but on OSX systems you need to use BPF, however the sample code I found is using "syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, syscall.IPPROTO_RAW)" and I am not sure how to get started with BPF.  I have also seen some people try to use gopacket instead of the x/net/ipv4 package.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
    "net"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var err error
    fd, _ := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, syscall.IPPROTO_RAW)

    addr := syscall.SockaddrInet4{
        Port: 0,
        Addr: [4]byte{127, 0, 0, 1},
    }
    p := pkt()

    _ = syscall.Sendto(fd, p, 0, &addr)
}

func pkt() []byte {
    h := ipv4.Header{
        Version:  4,
        Len:      20,
        TOS:      0,
        TotalLen: 85, // I can not seem to change this
        ID:       2,  // I can not seem to change this
        TTL:      64, // I can not seem to change this
        Protocol: 1,  // ICMP, This does not seem to work
        Dst:      net.IPv4(127, 0, 0, 1),
    }

    icmp := []byte{
        8, // type: echo request
        0, // code: not used by echo request
        0, // checksum (16 bit), we fill in below
        0,
        0, // identifier (16 bit). zero allowed.
        0,
        0, // sequence number (16 bit). zero allowed.
        0,
        0xC0, // Optional data. ping puts time packet sent here
        0xDE,
    }
    cs := csum(icmp)
    icmp[2] = byte(cs)
    icmp[3] = byte(cs >> 8)

    out, _ := h.Marshal()

    return append(out, icmp...)
}

func csum(b []byte) uint16 {
    var s uint32
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i += 2 {
        s += uint32(b[i+1])<<8 | uint32(b[i])
    }
    // add back the carry
    s = s>>16 + s&0xffff
    s = s + s>>16
    return uint16(^s)
}
```

If I print out the p variable that contains the packet data in Main() after the data comes back from pkt() it looks right:

```
DEBUG: (decimal) [69 0 60 0 0 0 0 0 64 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0 0 1 8 0 55 33 0 0 0 0 192 222]
DEBUG: (hex)      45 0 3c 0 0 0 0 0 40 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 7f 0 0 1 8 0 37 21 0 0 0 0 c0 de
```

And you can see that the protocol is set for "1" in the 10th byte.  But when we look at this packet in wireshark it looks like:

[image: wireshark screen shot]

Comment: On Linux, you need to be root to be able to do that, maybe it's the same on osx?

Comment: Thanks for picking up that omission, I have added that to the writeup.  Yes, I am running as root, you have to have root access to open raw sockets.

Comment: please show the hexdump

Comment: Added additional information to show the hexdumps

Comment: In the "man socket" manual on OSX it looks like there is an entry point of "PF_NDRV" that would probably do what I need.  As it appears that the "AF_INET" is really for things above layer 3.  But "PF_NDRV" does not seem to be part of the Go syscall.Socket library. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You should set the protocol to `syscall.IPPROTO_ICMP` instead of raw, no?

Comment: I was playing around with ICMP just an example.  Ultimately I need the ability to craft frames / packets for any protocol.  It just seems like either there is a bug or I am doing something wrong.  I hope I am just doing something wrong.

Comment: Perhaps Linux automatically sets the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option when you have a raw socket and OS X doesn't. I have tried adding `syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_HDRINCL, 1)` to fix it, but I am getting a problem with the packet I am sending now. Perhaps a byte order issue or something.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I was able to get this to work on OS X now. You need to make sure you are setting `IP_HDRINCL` socket option `syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_HDRINCL, 1)` and then you need to be careful building the packet. One trick that caught me for a LONG TIME was that, for some reason, for `Sendto` [OS X/BSD want the IP length in host byte order](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~braghava/notes/freebsd-sockets.txt), which in my case was LittleEndian, not BigEndian which is the typical network order. If you look at this code (I just kinda built the IP header myself, you can build it another way) it runs as expected.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    s, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, syscall.IPPROTO_RAW)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    addr := syscall.SockaddrInet4{Addr: [4]byte{127, 0, 0, 1}}

    data := makepacket()

    for _, v := range data {
        if v == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("00 ")
            continue
        } else if v < 0xf {
            fmt.Printf("0%x ", v)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%x ", v)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
    err = syscall.Sendto(s, data, 0, &addr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
}       

func makepacket() []byte {
    icmp := []byte{
        8, // type: echo request
        0, // code: not used by echo request
        0, // checksum (16 bit), we fill in below
        0,
        0, // identifier (16 bit). zero allowed.
        0,
        0, // sequence number (16 bit). zero allowed.
        0,
        0xC0, // Optional data. ping puts time packet sent here
        0xDE, 
    }
    cs := csum(icmp)
    icmp[2] = byte(cs)
    icmp[3] = byte(cs >> 8)

    buf := []byte{0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x95, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x0
0, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01}
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(buf[2:4], uint16(len(icmp) + len(buf)))
    return append(buf, icmp...)
}

func csum(b []byte) uint16 {
    var s uint32
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i += 2 {
        s += uint32(b[i+1])<<8 | uint32(b[i])
```

This code gives me this output in `# tcpdump -X -i lo0`

```
20:05:24.016465 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP echo request, id 0, seq 0, length 10
    0x0000:  4500 001e 9513 0000 4001 0000 7f00 0001  E.......@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0800 3721 0000 0000 c0de       ......7!......
20:05:24.016495 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP echo reply, id 0, seq 0, length 10
    0x0000:  4500 001e 3e4f 0000 4001 0000 7f00 0001  E...>O..@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0000 3f21 0000 0000 c0de       ......?!......
```

Comment: This works, and is very helpful.  I also got a response back from Mikio from the Go project with another solution that I will post below as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer I got back from Mikio on the Go project.  I am adding it here for other people that might be looking for a solution to this problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    ip := net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")
    proto := 1

    c, err := net.ListenPacket(fmt.Sprintf("ip4:%d", proto), "0.0.0.0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    p, err := ipv4.NewRawConn(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    b := []byte("HELLO-R-U-THERE")
    h := &ipv4.Header{
        Version:  ipv4.Version,
        Len:      ipv4.HeaderLen,
        TotalLen: ipv4.HeaderLen + len(b),
        ID:       12345,
        Protocol: proto,
        Dst:      ip.To4(),
    }
    if err := p.WriteTo(h, b, nil); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kinda cool; I should have known there'd be an easier solution. I haven't looked much through the `net/ipv4` package. Typically in Go you don't have to go down to syscalls like we were trying. For this type of networking it might also be useful to write these parts in C and just call the C from your Go code.